# The asynchronous callback function doesn't work for this program

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, settimeout

Hello I have this sheet of Javascript code :

```
var asyncFunction = function (cb) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        cb('accepted');
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
 };

var Applicant = function (applicant_name_var, applicant_age_var) {
    var name = applicant_name_var;
    var a = applicant_age_var;
    return {
        who_AM_I: function () {
            if (name == null) { return 'No Name'; }
            else {
                return name;
            }
        },
        INTERVIEWRESULT: function () {
            var result = 'pending';
            asyncFunction(function (result) {
             result = result;
            });
            return result;
        }
    };
};
```

What I am looking for is to change the value of result in INTERVIEWRESULT
from "pending" to "accepted".

Please could you help me to fix the code above

Comment: Wrap result into an object. You'll be able to return that object and change the status within the asyncFunction scope. Do it like: {status: 'pending'}. You should return a promise instead of the value, though.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand I still a beginner in Js ^^

Comment: You should study promises. such as [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or   [ECMA 6's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: It's totally impossible. When you `return` from the function, the string `'accepted'` has not yet been created. You cannot peek into the future.

Comment: Since it's an asynchronous method you aren't supposed to return a value, instead, return a promise of the value.